# Move a this cells value to this cell if it equals this

Tags: excel, excel-formula, cells, copying

I'm doing a project with inventory. Basically I enter a part number in one column, then 4 cells to the right of it i enter the description. The parts are old, and sometimes they are repeated. I would like a formula that allows me to do something like this; Enter a part number, if the part number has been entered in a previous cell, take the description (4 cells to the right of the part # cell) and insert it into the cell 4 cells to the right of the cell i entered the part number.

Example

```
A1="10-1111".....E1="part1"
A2..
A3..
A4..
A5="10-1111"....E5-(I want "Part1" inserted here)
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Looks like a simple VLOOKUP to me.

Comment: Thank you, I have yet to actually try using the vlookup, but the "duplicate" article is setting me on the right path.